# PyMongo cannot get $and + $or to work

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm using python 3, mongo version 2.6.4, and pymongo version 2.7. I can't get the following query to work...
This query is what I put directly into the mongo shell:

```
db.zoo.find({'animal': {'$and': [{'$ne': 'dog'}, {'$ne': 'cat'}]}}).limit(20).pretty()
```

(The limit and pretty is only there while I'm testing)
This is the error I get:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $and",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

I receive the same error when I use the $or operator:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

I did find a Jira that had been raised, but I wasn't sure if it related to the same issue
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12981

I've tried all the combinations I can think of, but I can't solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
I did attempt $nin but it returned nothing. Even though this is the Mongo shell query, I can't get it to work in PyMongo either, and I receive the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `implicit and` in this case. The following query should work

```
db.zoo.find({'animal': {$ne: 'dog', $ne: 'cat'}})
```

to make the `and explicit` you can write

```
db.zoo.find({$and: [{'animal': {$ne: 'dog'}},{'animal': {$ne: 'cat'}}]})
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you! :D

Comment: How can the first one work? Doesn't the second $ne overwrite the first within the same object? E.g if you do console.log({$ne: 'dog', $ne: 'cat'}). You only see "{$ne: 'cat'}".